# Date.parse behaving differently in FF and Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, date, mozilla

I have a jquery datepicker assigned to a textfield.The textfield is non editable and only backspace key can be used for removing date. I have used the following code for checking if the field is having valid date.This works perfectly in mozilla,but not in chrome.

```
<input type="text" class="date_field from_date" name="from_date" placeholder="From date">

//datepicker
$(".from_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
//only backspace keypress allowed
$(".date_field").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});

//check the date is valid.
//For example('2015-09-' is the value of textfield)
alert(Date.parse($('.from_date').val()));
//returns NaN in mozilla,but returns number in chrome
if (Date.parse($('.from_date').val())) {
    //do the rest code
}
```

Comment: Does it returns `NaN`?

Comment: @WisdmLabs mozilla returns NaN,but chrome gives me a number

Comment: `Date.parse` works fine on chrome, it returns same number as '2015-09-01' on your case. `Date.parse` is not a best method to test if date is formatted correctly. You have to use some regex to match your wanted date pattern. I suggest do T.J.Crowder check `dateString.test(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/)` first and then test if `Date.parse` doesn't return NaN

Comment: As `Date.parse` is not intended to test if a string represents a valid date, but to try and get a date from a given string, I would say this is actually not a case of "`Date.parse` not working in Chrome" but rather a case of "`Date.parse` behaving differently in FF and Chrome". I guess the title of this question should be reworded to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.parse):

> The String may be interpreted as a local time, a UTC time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the String. The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules (including extended years) called out in Date Time String Format (20.3.1.16). **If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.**

*(my emphasis)*

In this case, Chrome has adopted the heuristic that a missing day equates to the first day of the month, so it recognises "2015-09-" as the first of September. It does some other interesting things, too, like seeing "2015-09-31" as October 1st. (Which is largely in keeping with how JavaScript's `Date` automatically handles rollover.)

If you want to validate the format, you must do that using something that won't try to apply implementation-specific heuristics. For instance:

```
if (dateString.test(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/) {
    // It's in ####-##-## format. Still may not be valid, you can do more checking if necessary
}
```